# Многовариантность заголовков или названия с "или"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, прописная-строчная, или, заголовок

Как верно писать заголовок, в котором совмещены два названия одновременно?

Например:
Кошки-мышки или где справедливость?
Кошки-мышки или Где справедливость?
Кошки-мышки или "где справедливость"?
Кошки-мышки или "Где справедливость"?
Кошки-мышки или "где справедливость?"
Кошки-мышки или "Где справедливость?"

Какой же из этих вариантов будет верным и почему?
Правила будут одними и теми же (для любых знаков препинания в конце второго «присоединённого» названия) или написание будет отличаться?

К примеру, если вариант заголовка будет следующим:
*Кошки-мышки или нет в жизни справедливости*

Что делать с такими заголовками, если в первом названии должен стоять один знак препинания, а во втором — другой?

К примеру:
*Где в жизни справедливость или научиться играть в кошки-мышки*

Comment: >Под "подобными заглавиями" и в продолжении моего комментария подразумевались названия произведений типа «Двенадцатая ночь, или Что угодно».   

А к чему вы это? "Тихо сам с собою"? 
"Что угодно" - это вообще не вопросительная кострукция.
Вы еще "уточните", что в "Где раки зимуют" и "Куда Макар телят не гонял" вопросительный знак "традиционно опускается".

Comment: Хм, ненадолго вас хватило.

Comment: Простите, вы что-то сказали?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы оставила первый вариант, добавив запятую перед или.
Кошки-мышки, или где справедливость?

**Добавляю и исправляю.**

Была не права. ВОт что еще нашла в добавление к Лопатину.

Есть такой  государственный стандарт "Библиографическое обеспечение издательских и книготорговых процессов" 2010 года.

6.2.3 Основное заглавие может содержать альтернативное заглавие, соединенное с ним союзом «или» и записываемое с прописной буквы. Перед союзом «или» ставят запятую.

Романтики Интернета, или Новые мечтатели

Юмор, ирония, сарказм, или Как с оптимизмом относиться к жизни

Comment: Здесь "где" с прописной.

Кошки-мышки, или Где справедливость.

Comment: Соглашусь. Нашла большой список книг с подобными названиями, везде заглавная буква. И, конечно, везде запятая перед "или"

Comment: См. ПАС, § 195, п. б:

 Если наименование художественного произведения состоит из двух названий, соединенных союзом или, то с прописной буквы пишется также первое слово второго названия, напр.: «Двенадцатая ночь, или Что угодно», «Ирония судьбы, или С лёгким паром».


Для Docentl:
читайте хотя бы Пушкина (...Обиды не страшась, не требуя венца; Хвалу и клевету приемли равнодушно, И не оспоривай глупца), а не, прости господи, какого-то нелепого Вербина — все полезней будет.

Comment: @Ларf, а как начет вопросительного знака? Вас ее смучает, что так он относится ко всей фразе? Попробуйте переставить части местами. 
В вашем списке нет ничего подобного?  
«"Где справедливость?" или Кошки-мышки». Я другой пунктцации здесь представить не могу.

Comment: К сожалению, среди списка книг нет ни одного вопросительного предложения.

Comment: Вопросительного знака в подобных заголовках и не может быть, он традиционно опускается, что и показывает "большой список книг с подобными названиями".

Comment: @Marina-ja, вы заблуждаетесь. 

Что такое счастье? – стихотворения Э. Асадова, Н. Асеева, книги  А. Суркова и С. Михалкова.
Что делать? – роман Н. Чернышевского и статья В. Ленина. 
Кто виноват? –  роман А. Герцена 
Как нам обустроить Россию? – статья А. Солженицына. 
Любите ли Вы Брамса? – роман Ф. Саган.
А вы могли бы? –  стихотворение В. Маяковского.
Когда же придет настоящий день? – статья Н. Добролюбова.
Кто он? – стихотворения А. Майкова, С. Маршака и В. Маяковского.
Вы слышите их? – роман Н. Саррот.
Что такое хорошо и что такое плохо? – стихотворение В. Маяковского.

(с) Грамота.

Comment: Нет причин считать, что вопросительный знак "традичионно опускается" в случае двойного названия, просто не было примеров тог, что он там был нужен.

Comment: О том, что предложение вопросительное, свидетельствует не только вопросительный знак.  Просто это список рукописных текстов 17-19 веков. Там действительно подобного нет.

Comment: Ну, Добролюбов и Герцен - впролне себе XIX век.

@Ларf, а ведь в "Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром!" в оригинальном названии знак есть. Нет причин считать, что вопросительный знак чем-то отличается.

Comment: Это была реплика в ответ на комментарий Марины.

Comment: Под "подобными заглавиями" и в продолжении моего комментария подразумевались названия произведений типа «Двенадцатая ночь, или Что угодно».

Comment: Вообще-то "Где справедливость?" - тоже явно риторический вопрос и его можно опустить. Другое дело, если вопрос действительно нужен...

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится второй вариант. Не знаю, соответствует ли он правилам, но он более функционален. Позволяет сразу видеть, что в заглавии соединены разнородные части.

Думаю, такой заголовок - это журналистский = авторский прием, так что автор может сам распоряжаться синтаксисом.

Каюсь, сама люблю эффектные заголовки. Просмотрела список своих научно-популярных статей - больше половины заголовков в виде вопроса ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это вопрос нигде толком не изложен.
Самом близкое, что удалось найти это «Сквозь зеркало, и Что там нашла Алиса» (и еще несколько подобных из менее известных произведений). Но здесь нет вопросительного знака.
А он в корне меняет ситуацию. Боюсь, что в данном случае без кавычек не обойтись. Так что я за вариант с кавычками и, разумеется, запятой, о которой вам уже сказали. «Кошки-мышки или "Где справделивость?"». *Внешние кавычки - не часть названия*.
А вообще я попробую спросить у людей причастных.

//==========

***Короче так**. Предлагается или снять вопросительный знак или распространить его действие на обе части. "Двойные" заголовки истории с вопросительным знаком только при одной из чатей науке неизсвестны.* К сожалению, чего-то такого я ожидал изначально. Вопрос о двух знаках я просто побоялся задать.

//==========
Так. На основании примеров формулирую, насколько понял, ***общие рекомендации***.

Кавычки не использовать. В случае, если знак относится к первой части запятую опускать, миритсья с тем, что знак стоит в середине предложения. В отношении знака при второй части - мириться с двусмысленностью.

Таким образом, допустимые (если "деваться некуда") варианты пунктуационного оформления:
"Кошки-мышки, или Где справедливость",  
"Кошки-мышки! или Где справедливость",
"Кошки-мышки, или Где справедливость?",
"Кошки-мышки! или Где справедливость?", 
"Где справедливость, или Кошки-мышки",
"Где справедливость? или Кошки-мышки",
"Где справедливость, или Кошки-мышки!" (= "Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром!"), 
"Где справедливость? или Кошки-мышки!".

Выбор, разумеется, диктуется авторским замыслом. Абсолютно соответвует правилам и смыслу только вариант без знаков. Но если без них - никак, то выбирайте.

//====

Тем не менее... 
Обнаружилась такая вот цитата:

*Фильм является авторской экранизацией пьесы Эмиля Брагинского и Эльдара Рязанова «С лёгким паром!, или Однажды в новогоднюю ночь…»* 
(Вики).
Вопрос о правильности оформалния названия пьесы задан Справке на Грамоте. Если будут результаты, сообщу.

Comment: Ага, а здесь собрались одни "непричастные". И чего, спрашивается, собрались.

Comment: Марина, простите, давайте не будем выдавать себя за тех, кем не являемся. Я не спрашиваю, кто вы есть, но точно не корректор.

Comment: Вы, как всегда, ошибаетесь.

Comment: Вы - корректор?

Ответа не последовало. Что и требовалось доказать.

Comment: Что бы я ни ответила, вы будете доказывать обратное.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял.

Comment: Docentl, я не люблю, когда мне указывают, что я должна делать. Если я вам скажу: "И вам с этим придется смириться", думаю, вам это не понравится так же, как мне не понравилось ваше замечание.

Comment: Marina-ja, Вам никто не указывает. Вы ищите повод для скандалов по собственной инициативе.
DocentI, не стоило. Я не нуждаюсь в установлении победителя. А так получился новый виток напряженности, о чем пришлось сообщить модератору.

Comment: > Если я вам скажу: "И вам с этим придется смириться", думаю, вам это не понравится так же, как мне не понравилось ваше замечание.  

@Marina-ja, я смирюсь. Я смирная. ;-)) Да и чувство юмора поможет.  
Честно, такие слова не возбудят во мне _никаких_ отрицательных чувств.