# Названия, разделённые "или"

Tags: пунктуация, названия, или

Я часто встречаю книги с названиями "A или B" (не могу привести конкретный пример, не помню), и перед "или" стоит запятая. Всегда считал это ошибкой и заносил в список (помогаю составлять библиотечный каталог) без запятой. Сегодня подумал: а может всё-таки есть причины так писать в названиях. И не только книг, но и фильмов, и чего-то ещё.

Comment: Это еще полбеды. Вот если первая част названия требует вопросительного или восклицательного знака... *"Хармс! Чармс! Шардам! или Школа клоунов."*

Comment: А вообше, Артем, рекомендую почаще знакомиться с историей вопросов на ресурсе. Вы уже не первый раз поыторяеете ранее заданные и отвеченные вопросы. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4496 Не в обиду Вам будь сказано.

Comment: Я обычно смотрю, нету ли ответа, begemothus, и сейчас перед тем, как спросить, поиском посмотрел на "или", но там не нашёл. Хотя если бы я искал "или названия", нашёл бы как раз Вашу ссылку. Постараюсь получше искать в следующий раз. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Запятая ставится перед союзом или в названиях литературных произведений, состоящих из двух наименований (второе название тоже пишется с прописной буквы): «Двенадцатая ночь, или Как вам угодно» (Шекспир); «Похождения Чичикова, или Мёртвые души» (Н.В. Гоголь); «Воевода, или Сон на Волге» (А. Н. Островский); «Золотой ключик, или Приключения Буратино» (А. Н. Толстой).

> Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация Розенталь.Д.Э.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Выходит, там всё правильно было!